# How do I make named arguments in ELisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I figured that since Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp seemed so closely related syntax wise, I could just follow the example code I found on [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Keyword_arguments), but it turns out that I was wrong.

The code in question looks like this:

```
(defun print-name (&key first (last "?"))
  (princ last)
  (when first
    (princ ", ")
    (princ first))
  (values))
```

And according to RosettaCode it should do the following:

```
> (print-name)
  ?
> (print-name :first "John")
  ?, John
> (print-name :last "Doe")
  Doe
> (print-name :first "John" :last "Doe")
  Doe, John
```

Now, here's the thing; whenever I try to run that function in my ELisp interpreter, I get the following error:

```
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (&key first (last "?")) (princ la\
st) (if first (progn (princ ", ") (princ first))) (values)), 0
```

I'm not routined enough in lisp to know what that's supposed to mean, and no amount of *Googling* has lead me any closer to an answer.

So what's the correct way of doing this in Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 23):

Since Emacs Lisp does not support keyword arguments directly, you'll need to emulate these, either with `cl-defun` as in the other answer, or by parsing the arguments as plist:

```
(defun print-name (&rest args)
  (let ((first (plist-get args :first))
        (last (or (plist-get args :last) "?")))
    (princ last)
    (when first
      (princ ", ")
      (princ first))))
```

`&rest args` tells Emacs to put all function arguments into a single list.  `plist-get` extracts a value from a property list, that is, a list of the format `(key1 value1 key2 value2 …)`.  Effectively, a plist is a flattened alist.

Together this lets you call `print-name` just like in your question:

```
> (print-name)
  ?
> (print-name :first "John")
  ?, John
> (print-name :last "Doe")
  Doe
> (print-name :first "John" :last "Doe")
  Doe, John
```

Answer (score 20):

Elisp's `defun` does not support `&key` (it does support `&optional` and `&rest`, though).  There is a macro that lets you define functions using `&key`.  In Emacs 24.3 and later you can require `cl-lib` and use `cl-defun`:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-defun print-name (&key first (last "?"))
   ...
```

In earlier Emacs versions, the same functionality is in the `cl` library under the name `defun*`:

```
(require 'cl)
(defun* print-name (&key first (last "?"))
   ...
```

The `cl-lib` library is preferred to `cl`, since it keeps the namespace tidy by prefixing all symbols with `cl-`; however, if you need compatibility with earlier Emacs versions, you may prefer `cl` and `defun*`.

---

The function in the example also contains a call to the function `values`.  This function is specific to Common Lisp, but is available as `cl-values` in `cl-lib`, and `values` in `cl`.

However, the alternatives don't work exactly the same as their Common Lisp counterpart.  Common Lisp has the concept of multiple return values.  For example, calling `(values 1 2 3)` would return three values — and calling `(values)` as above would return zero values. The Emacs Lisp functions emulate multiple return values by way of lists, and also redefines `multiple-value-bind` to match.  This means that the call `(cl-values)` will just return `nil` (the empty list).

In such an Emacs Lisp function, you'd either explicitly specify the return value as `nil`, or just leave it out altogether, leaving the return value of the last form as the return value of the function, since the caller is not expected to use the return value.

Comment: this doesn't exactly work, I get an error saying `Symbol's function definition is void: values`

Comment: Right, the `values` function is another Common Lisp speciality.  It's called `cl-values` in `cl-lib`.

Comment: Doing that just makes it return nil rather than print anything...  At least it doesn't produce an error

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `elisp` [does **not** support named arguments per-se](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_optional_params.html). However, you can emulate that feature by passing an `alist` to a function, [check this for a guide on `alists`](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs_manual/elisp/Association-Lists.html).

At the core, this means that you pass a *map-like* data structure into the function, hence you need to take care of both wrapping (composition of arguments into the `alist`) and unwrapping (decomposition into variables / checking of required / optional values) yourself.

Creating of the input structure is simple, just compose cons cells of the variable symbol and its value:

```lisp
(print-name '((first . "John") (last . "Doe")))
```

Reading is even simpler: just use `assoc` to obtain the corresponding value:

```lisp
(assoc 'last '((first . "John") (last . "Doe")))
; => (last . "Doe")
(assoc 'middle '((first . "John") (last . "Doe")))
; => nil
```

Hence, `print-name` could look like this:

```lisp
(defun print-name (alist)
  (let ((first (assoc 'first alist))
        (last (assoc 'last alist)))
    (if last
        (princ (cdr last))
      (error "Missing last name!"))
    (when first
      (princ ", ")
      (princ (cdr first)))))
```

Comment: Idiomatically, you'd rather use `&rest args` and parse `args` as plist, which has less syntactic clutter: `(print-name :first "John" :last "Doe")`.